# Discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subseteq G$ is a lattice iff the locally symmetric space $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ has finite volume

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

I'm trying to see how lattices can be defined in terms of the volume of the associated locally symmetric space. In Exercise §1C#6 of Dave Witte Morris [book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106063), one is asked to prove the following:

> Let $K$ be a compact subgroup of a Lie group $G$, and $Γ$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$ that acts freely on $G/K$.
>
> Show that $Γ \backslash G$ has finite volume if and only if $Γ \backslash G/K$ has finite volume.

I don't quote see how to solve this. To begin with, shouldn't $(G,K)$ be a Riemannian symmetric pair in order for $\Gamma \backslash G/K$ to have the structure of locally symmetric space and thus have a Riemannian metric?

Comment: Neither $G/K$ nor $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ need to be symmetric spaces in order for this question to make sense. They are (locally) homogeneous spaces, and that's enough.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sounds reasonable to me, do you happen to have a reference for this general phenomena?

Comment: I do not have it in front of me, but check Ragnunathan's book "Discrete subgroups of Lie groups". In any case, a proof is relatively straightforward application of the Fubini's theorem once you realize that $\Gamma\backslash G$ fibers over $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ with compact fibers of equal volume. (Here you use a Riemannian metric on $G$ which is left $G$-invariant and right $K$-invariant.)